# Impersonation as Site Owner, workflow is cancelled when setting

Tags: workflow, error, impersonation

Good day.

We have a simple list workflow that uses Impersonation to give Contribute Rights to a user via Replace Contribute Item. The workflow is created by our site Collection Admin.

So when i ran it when the item in the list is changed, it was working fine. But when i edit the workflow, adding another user (by current item lookup) to have contribute rights and save it, i get a prompt that it will be run under the user privildge , and continue if this is the intended behaviour. so i saved it. But when i ran the workflow, It Get's cancelled.  I am a Site Owner with full control rights , so i can create/edit lists and workflows.

It seems that i can't set permissions on impersonation when i'm Site Owner, even though I have full control. Does it work this way? Do I need to become a Site Collection Admin to get
impersonation running?

Im relatively new to sharepoint 2010 and ive been using this for the past weeks.

Thanks for the advice.